# SQL left join on column ignoring anything post (

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to join 2 tables via 2 columns however, the left tables has entity values after them that I want to discard and they always start with (. Example: 1256390(1) or 23452(9), I need to disregard the (1) and (9)

Code Below

```
SELECT
A.Case_ID
A.Entity_ID
B.Entity_ID
B.Source
FROM Case_Table A
LEFT JOIN Source_Table B
ON A.Entity_ID = B.Entity_ID 
WHERE B.Source = 'Internal';
```

Nothing that I have tried works to this point.

Comment: `WHERE B.Source = 'Internal'` You pretty much turn your `LEFT JOIN` into `JOIN`.

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the part of the entity ID before `(`.

Comment: If you need `B.Source = 'Internal'` condition - add it to `ON` .

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want the second table to be in the select statement?

```
SELECT
A.Case_ID
A.Entity_ID
B.Entity_ID
B.Source
FROM Case_Table A
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Source_Table B
    WHERE A.Entity_ID = B.Entity_ID
);
```